# User provides answer in question text

Tags: discussion, questions

What is the proper way to handle a user providing the answer to their question in the question text itself?

Of course they can be prodded to provide an actual "answer", but should the answer text be removed from the question, even if the user doesn't make a proper answer?

For example: [Derby Timestamp Comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18237293/derby-timestamp-comparison-solved)

I'm hesitant to remove content, but the question isn't in a proper form.

Comment: If the OP does not respond in a reasonable time (e.g. couple of days) then yes, edit the answer out and post it as community wiki. Order must be kept!

Comment: And if the user hasn't been active recently just move it to an answer right away; if you think it's reasonably likely they'll be able to act on it, then feel free to wait for them to answer.

Comment: The question asks if his SQL is correct.  Shouldn't the correct response to be to leave a comment telling them the answer is "Yes, your SQL string is correct"?

Comment: The question has been edited using @Servy 's suggestion: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18237293/revisions

Comment: @JohnnyBones Look at the revision history; you're looking at it after it was edited to remove his own answer.